# replace the items instead of giving the whole path

Tags: javascript, json, jsonpath

In this json, when ever I find the following Items, I need to do the base64 encoding of the value and replace it with encoding value using javascript.

For these Keys pbId, remmedId, remId, pbMedId.
I need replace the corresponding values with their base64 encoded values.

```
{
    "output": {
        "rem": {
            "rems": {
                "lastNotif": null,
                "remmed": [
                    {
                        "pbId": "201734",
                        "remmedId": "2803790",
                        "remId": "250004",
                        "class": "com.burst.zumba"
                    }, {
                        "pbId": "190244",
                        "remmedId": "2803788",
                        "remId": "250004",
                        "class": "com.burst.zumba"
                    }
                ],
                "remType": "DAY",
                "notifTime": "17:30",
                "class": "com.burst.zumba",
                "enabled": "Y",
                "lastTime": "2014-08-25 16:26:05",
                "addedTime": "2014-08-25 16:26:05",
                "remFreq": "HOLI",
                "name": "test1",
                "remId": "250004",
                "remOut": [],
                "status": "Y",
                "pbId": "1250003"
            },
            "List": [
                {
                    "SSType": "MJD",
                    "rems": null,
                    "prsName": "DrJohnSmith",
                    "prsPhone": "5555555555",
                    "expDate": "2015-04-14",
                    "lastDate": "2014-08-13 01:00:12",
                    "issueDate": null,
                    "modDate": "2014-08-27 10:15:22",
                    "writtDate": "2014-04-14",
                    "pbMedId": "2017346",
                    "name": "CARDIO",
                    "SSId": "237421923",
                    "pbId": "1250007653",
                    "createdDate": "2014-08-27 10:15:22"
                }, {
                    "SSType": "JCX",
                    "rems": null,
                    "prsName": "Dr John Doe",
                    "prsPhone": "5555555555",
                    "expDate": "2015-04-14",
                    "lastDate": "2014-08-13 01:00:12",
                    "issueDate": null,
                    "modDate": "2014-09-02 17:38:47",
                    "writtDate": "2014-04-14",
                    "pbMedId": "1902449",
                    "name": "VICTORY",
                    "class": "237342123",
                    "pbId": "12503003",
                    "createdDate": "2014-08-26 14:32:08"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I can go thru like output.rem.rems.remmed and find the value. But Is there any way that I can do like global search and replace my objects instead of giving the whole path

Comment: It's possible but not desirable. It's an object you can iterate it recursively.

Comment: How to do iterate it recursively

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code recursively iterates over your objects. When it finds the keys it will base64 encode them using [`btoa`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/Base64_encoding_and_decoding). I've written the output back with `JSON.stringify` to show the result as test case.

To use: call `convertToBase64`, the first argument is the data object, all other arguments are optional. You can add keys as arguments.

```js
var data = {
    "output": {
        "rem": {
            "rems": {
                "lastNotif": null,
                "remmed": [
                    {
                        "pbId": "201734",
                        "remmedId": "2803790",
                        "remId": "250004",
                        "class": "com.burst.zumba"
                    }, {
                        "pbId": "190244",
                        "remmedId": "2803788",
                        "remId": "250004",
                        "class": "com.burst.zumba"
                    }
                ],
                "remType": "DAY",
                "notifTime": "17:30",
                "class": "com.burst.zumba",
                "enabled": "Y",
                "lastTime": "2014-08-25 16:26:05",
                "addedTime": "2014-08-25 16:26:05",
                "remFreq": "HOLI",
                "name": "test1",
                "remId": "250004",
                "remOut": [],
                "status": "Y",
                "pbId": "1250003"
            },
            "List": [
                {
                    "SSType": "MJD",
                    "rems": null,
                    "prsName": "DrJohnSmith",
                    "prsPhone": "5555555555",
                    "expDate": "2015-04-14",
                    "lastDate": "2014-08-13 01:00:12",
                    "issueDate": null,
                    "modDate": "2014-08-27 10:15:22",
                    "writtDate": "2014-04-14",
                    "pbMedId": "2017346",
                    "name": "CARDIO",
                    "SSId": "237421923",
                    "pbId": "1250007653",
                    "createdDate": "2014-08-27 10:15:22"
                }, {
                    "SSType": "JCX",
                    "rems": null,
                    "prsName": "Dr John Doe",
                    "prsPhone": "5555555555",
                    "expDate": "2015-04-14",
                    "lastDate": "2014-08-13 01:00:12",
                    "issueDate": null,
                    "modDate": "2014-09-02 17:38:47",
                    "writtDate": "2014-04-14",
                    "pbMedId": "1902449",
                    "name": "VICTORY",
                    "class": "237342123",
                    "pbId": "12503003",
                    "createdDate": "2014-08-26 14:32:08"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

 function convertToBase64(obj)
 {
  var keys = Object.keys(obj);
  var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1); //copy all arguments except the first.
  for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; ++i)
  {
   if ( Object.prototype.toString.call(obj[keys[i]]) == "[object Object]" || Object.prototype.toString.call(obj[keys[i]]) == "[object Array]")
   {
    convertToBase64.apply(this, [obj[keys[i]]].concat(args));
   }
   else
   {
    if ( args.indexOf(keys[i]) > -1)
    {
     obj[keys[i]] = btoa(obj[keys[i]]);
    }
   }
  }
 }

 convertToBase64(data, "remmedId", "pbMedId", "remId", "pbId");
 document.write(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Comment: Thank you what if I want to do a encrypt using cryptoJs encrypt function with some secretphrase

Comment: Implement the library, read the spec and replace the `btoa` function with that from cryptojs

Comment: adding as another answer as I can't keep the whole